# file system related query

Tags: file, file-io, operating-system

In a 32-bit file system, disk block address are 4 bytes (32 bits), in a 64 bit file system, there are 8 bytes. Thus given a file system block size of 1024 bytes and a block address size of 64 bits, an indirect block can refer to 128 blocks. What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

If a block can store 1024 bytes, then how many addresses to other blocks can I store in that block, if addresses are 8 bytes. 1024/8 == 128

Comment: So it means that the indirect block will have those many number of pointers inside it, right?

Comment: Will have? No, not necessarily; wrong phrase at least. Can store? Yes. Just because the space exists doesn't  mean you're using it. But if you're writing a file system, you can use blocks however you want.